# Problems reversing output in Python - Student question

Tags: python, reverse

I'm attempting to do lesson 2 of my python coding class and I'm running into a misunderstanding.  The book asks me to **"Extend to also output in reverse."**

The code should output like this (assuming input 99, 3.77, z, Howdy)

```
Enter integer (0 - 155):
99
Enter float:
3.77
Enter character:
z
Enter string:
Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
```

However when I run the code I am getting this error:

```
Enter integer (0 - 155):
Enter float:
Enter character:
Enter string:
99 3.77 z Howdy 

Enter integer (0 - 155):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py",
```

This is what my code actually looks like:

```
# FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four 
values on a single line separated by a space

userInt = int(input('Enter integer (0 - 155):\n'))
userFloat = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
userCharacter = str(input('Enter character:\n'))
userString = str(input('Enter string:\n'))
print(userInt, userFloat, userCharacter, userString, '\n')   

# FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse

userInt = int(input('Enter integer (0 - 155):\n'))
userFloat = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
userCharacter = str(input('Enter character:\n'))
userString = str(input('Enter string:\n'))
print(userInt, userFloat, userCharacter, userString, userString, 
userCharacter, userFloat, userInt)
```

I've tried a few different things but no matter what I do it keeps highlighting a space after the 'Howdy' and then highlighting a return then printing out that traceback error message.  I dont know what it means and I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thanks so much for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for inputs to output two times:

```
# FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four values on a single line separated by a space

userInt = int(input('Enter integer (0 - 155):\n'))
userFloat = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
userCharacter = input('Enter character:\n')
userString = input('Enter string:\n')
print(userInt, userFloat, userCharacter, userString, '\n')   

# FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse

userInt = int(input('Enter integer (0 - 155):\n'))
userFloat = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
userCharacter = input('Enter character:\n')
userString = input('Enter string:\n')
print(userInt, userFloat, userCharacter, userString,'\n'+userString, 
userCharacter, userFloat, userInt)
```

Example Output:

```
Enter integer (0 - 155):
99
Enter float:
3.77
Enter character:
z
Enter string:
Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy 

Enter integer (0 - 155):
99
Enter float:
3.77
Enter character:
z
Enter string:
Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy 
Howdy z 3.77 99
```

Then for once:

```
userInt = int(input('Enter integer (0 - 155):\n'))
userFloat = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
userCharacter = input('Enter character:\n')
userString = input('Enter string:\n')
print(userInt, userFloat, userCharacter, userString,'\n'+userString, 
userCharacter, userFloat, userInt)
```

Example Output:

```
Enter integer (0 - 155):
99
Enter float:
3.77
Enter character:
z
Enter string:
Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy 
Howdy z 3.77 99
```

Comment: what does the + before userString do?  does it remove the space?  I had tried it with the '\n' in there but it was adding a space before the Howdy on the second line.

Comment: @Amorky Yup, it does, because `,` does a space but `+` just concatenates the strings

Comment: @Amorky Your Welcome,Happy that i helped, 

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
user_str = input('Enter string:\n')

print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_str)
print(user_str, user_char, user_float, user_int)
print(user_int,'converted to a character is',chr(user_int))
```

Comment: shameless duplication of the answer from TMB.

Comment: Yea, I'm new to the site. I was more or less trying to say that TMB answer worked for me. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I got an output, it looped once through then the second time it printed forward and reverse.

Could it have to do with this line not being in comments `values on a single line separated by a space` ?

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 verbose.py 
> Enter integer (0 - 155):
> 99
> Enter float:
> 3.77
> Enter character:
> z
> Enter string:
> Howdy
> 99 3.77 z Howdy 
>
> Enter integer (0 - 155):
> 99
> Enter float:
> 3.7
> Enter character:
> z
> Enter string:
> Howdy
> 99 3.7 z Howdy Howdy z 3.7 99
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_character = input('Enter character:\n')
user_string = str(input('Enter string:\n'))

print(user_int, user_float, user_character, user_string)
print(user_string, user_character, user_float, user_int)

print(user_int,'converted to a character is',chr(user_int))
```

Comment: Let me know what you guys think. There are other ways to solve this but this seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))

user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))

user_char = input('Enter character:\n')

user_str = input('Enter string:\n')

print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_str)

print(user_str, user_char, user_float, user_int)

print(user_int,'converted to a character is',chr(user_int))
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have `'\n'` between `userString,'\n'+userString,`